# Text in tabs on profile page is not centered

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

On my Stack Overflow profile page, I noticed that the text in the top tabs is not centred, which appears to be due to the image on the `Developer Story` tab.

**These screenshots illustrate what I mean:**

[image: Profile tabs]
[image: Annotated profile tabs]

The issue seems to be because of the image, because when I go into the `Developer Story` section of my profile, the image disappears, causing the tabs to become shorter and allowing the text to be centred properly.

[image: Developer Story tab]
[image: Annotated profile tabs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now. Thanks for reporting it!